# PHP SOAP WSDL cache not working

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i'm troubled with soap wdl cache directory where i set to save my soap object. I've set the `soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"` in php.ini. I don't know how it's not saving any files in /tmp folder after i create the object, it's just stay empty in there.
i have set `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=3` and restart the apache service too.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved. when making new soap object give `cache_wsdl` option.

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://blahblah.blah?wsdl",array("trace"=>true,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH));
```